# Can Coulomb branches have symplectic resolutions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

My question is about Coulomb branches of a $3D$ $\mathcal{N}=4$ supersymmetric gauge theory, in the sense of Bravermann, Finkelberg and Nakajima *Towards a mathematical definition of Coulomb
branches of 3-dimensional N=4 gauge theories II*.

It has been recently shown by G. Bellamy (see paper [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11005-023-01724-5)) that all Coulomb branches are symplectic singularities.

I remember to hear in a talk that a general Coulomb branch will not have a symplectic resolution of singularities (but my memory might be wrong).

Well, me question then is: what is known about Coulomb branches having symplectic resolutions?